# stm32 WFI not triggering

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt, stm32, intrinsics

I am using an STM32L151 (Cortex-M3) and configuring an external interrupt on a gpio pin:

```
/* Enable clocks */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SYSCFG, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_SPI3, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_TIM9, ENABLE);

/* ExtInt Input */
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStr;
GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_40MHz;
GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_PuPd  = GPIO_PuPd_DOWN;
GPIO_InitStr.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_13;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStr);

/* Interrupts on EXTINT */
SYSCFG_EXTILineConfig(EXTI_PortSourceGPIOC, EXTI_PinSource13);
EXTI_InitTypeDef ExtiInitStr = {EXTI_Line13, EXTI_Mode_Interrupt, EXTI_Trigger_Rising, ENABLE};
EXTI_Init(&ExtiInitStr);
NVIC_InitTypeDef NvicInitStr = {EXTI15_10_IRQn, 0, 0, ENABLE};
NVIC_Init(&NvicInitStr);
```

My main.c eventually reaches a point where I have:

```
    __enable_irq();
//...program related code..
    __ASM volatile ("wfi");
```

At this point, the processor does NOT wake up from a the external pin going high.
If I replace the WFI line instead with

```
while(1);
```

the interrupt is triggered properly. I tried to follow examples but did not find something different. (I use ST-Link/V2 debugger,  GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors Toolchain & Eclipse plug-ins, with gdb and openOCD, if this matters)

Grateful for any hints!

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with the LowPower (LP) clocks? To my understanding they should be enabled by default, right?

Comment: According to the documentation, WFI puts the processor simply in sleep mode, and any interrupt, especially EXT should wake him up.
Plus I am using PC13 which is for this chip a WKUP pin. But to use this function I would have to configure the pin as AlternativeFunction and not Gpio input and when I do that I get no interrupts at all (even with the while loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was actually solved by decreasing the PLL speed. My config is:

```
/* HCLK = SYSCLK /1*/
RCC->CFGR |= (uint32_t)RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1;

/* PCLK2 = HCLK /1*/
RCC->CFGR |= (uint32_t)RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1;

/* PCLK1 = HCLK /1*/
RCC->CFGR |= (uint32_t)RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV1;

/*  PLL configuration */
RCC->CFGR &= (uint32_t)((uint32_t)~(RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC | RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL |
                                    RCC_CFGR_PLLDIV));
RCC->CFGR |= (uint32_t)(RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSI | RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL6 | RCC_CFGR_PLLDIV3);
```

And I verify that the problem is fixed when I replace RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL6 with RCC_CFGR_PLLMUL3. I cannot explain this, I don't know if it is related with the debugger speed or anything else.

Comment: What is the source of the signal going to the pin? If it's a button or switch, maybe you needed debouncing.

Comment: No it was another processor. But anyway the interrupt was triggering with while(1), and even a non-debounced button would trigger it, just possibly many times instead of one.